# Android EditText Hidden

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

In Android, I have a Parent `RelativeLayout`.
Inside that I have, a `ScrollView` --> `TableLayout`

The `TableLayout` contains around 25 Form items (`TextView : EditText`) combination.

The issue here is, whenever the `EditText` is selected, the SoftInput keyboard hides the `EditText` and hence the user cannot view where he is typing the text.

Sample Layout file.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="#FFFFFF"
 android:gravity="fill"
 android:orientation="vertical" >

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/retailinfoscroller"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_below="@+id/logininputtime"
 android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
 android:scrollbars="vertical" >

<TableLayout
 android:id="@+id/newstoreregtable"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:fadeScrollbars="true"
 android:stretchColumns="1" >

 <TableRow >

 <TextView
 android:layout_width="120dip"
 android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
 android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
 android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
 android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
 android:gravity="right"
 android:text="@string/strretailerid"
 android:textColor="#000000"
 android:textSize="16dip" />

 <EditText
 android:id="@+id/editretailerid"
 android:layout_width="120dip"
 android:layout_height="45dip"
 android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
 android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
 android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
 android:layout_weight="0.6"
 android:background="@drawable/edittextsample"
 android:clickable="false"
 android:cursorVisible="false"
 android:editable="false"
 android:singleLine="true" >
 </EditText>
 </TableRow>

 <TableRow></TableRow>
 </TableLayout>
 </ScrollView>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Basically I just want to have my `EditText` visible whenever user wants to type in.

I have gone through the forum, but cannot find the fix.

Comment: have you tryied using android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" ?

Comment: @Nirav, have you tryied my code?

Comment: Frankenstein : Thanks for you answer. I added that and now I get the desired behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In manifest add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`  under the Activity tag..

Comment: I have tried android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize", the behaviour is same.

Answer (score 1):

Do in the Android Manifest file:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize|adjustPan"
```

Also you need to add following code in the activity's OnCreate function:

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

I hope this helps.....

Comment: For me, the crucial flag is "adjustPan".  You don't need the onCreate code, though.  It suffices to "or" the flag "stateHidden" and leave out "stateVisible".